# FileNotFoundException when initialising a FileWriter with path

Tags: java, string, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a `string str="\Users\name\Desktop\Folder1\test.txt".`
I have the following code:

```
BufferedWriter fw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(str));
fw1.write(t);
fw1.close();
```

I am getting run time error `FileNotFound`, for this.
Even if i use `FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(str);`
I got the same error.
I am doing this in linux.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Print the exception message and print the 'str' as well to find out how the program is reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, either escape the `\` character (`\\`) or even better use the `\` character which does not need escaping and will spare you the trouble. However, there is a third option, using `File.separator` instead of hardcoding which might be a little extra work but will make your code bulletproof: `string str="" + File.separator + "Users"+ File.separator + "name"+ File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Folder1" + File.separator + "test.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\\` instead of `\` or use a `/` instead of `\`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `/` instead of `\` (even on a Windows system).

Furthermore, you didn't define a correct path. It doesn't exist on a "normal" Linux-System (like Ubuntu, Debian...). Maybe you mean something like "/home/name/Desktop/Folder1/test.txt" ?